# scrape <span> tag text using BeautifulSoup has no text attribute

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i have scraped a forum page, i have saved all the posts in a list called as post_list. but it seem's that i can't go any further and find the post author:

here is what i get in running command's without trying to find the text:

```
for post in post_list:
    print post.findAll("span" , {"itemprop" : "name"})
```

this give's me :

```
[<span class="hide" itemprop="name">00Amin</span>]
[<span class="hide" itemprop="name">arminheidari</span>]
[<span class="hide" itemprop="name">Zapad</span>]
[<span class="hide" itemprop="name">iMosi</span>]
[<span class="hide" itemprop="name">arminheidari</span>]
[<span class="hide" itemprop="name">alen</span>]
[<span class="hide" itemprop="name">mahdavi3d</span>]
[<span class="hide" itemprop="name">arminheidari</span>]
[<span class="hide" itemprop="name">alen</span>]
[<span class="hide" itemprop="name">rezatizi</span>]
[<span class="hide" itemprop="name">Trooper</span>]
[<span class="hide" itemprop="name">rasoolmr</span>]
[<span class="hide" itemprop="name">arminheidari</span>]
[<span class="hide" itemprop="name">iMosi</span>]
[<span class="hide" itemprop="name">anybody</span>]
```

but, if i try the same code with a .text:

```
for post in post_list:
    print post.findAll("span" , {"itemprop" : "name"}).text
```

i get :

```
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'text'
```

if i cheat and save the for loop result in a variable(or a list) and then try the get the text from there, i fail again!

```
posts = []
for post in post_list:
     posts.append(post.findAll("span",  {"itemprop" : "name"}))
```

i get no error but i cant find any .text property again

i have searched and tested some other question's i have find, but they don't work.

Comment: Because it's not `.text` but `.string`, according to the documentation?

Comment: nah, it doesn't have a .string property too...

Comment: @spectras Both `text` and `string` are available in BS element. The problem was, `findAll()`returns multiple elements in the form of `ResultSet`, which doesn't have either `text` or `string`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message clearly suggests, that's because `findAll()` returns `ResultSet` which doesn't have attribute `text`. You need to iterate through the result, or using list comprehension :

```
for post in post_list:
    print [span.text for span in post.findAll("span" , {"itemprop" : "name"})]
```

If there is always only one `span` element in each `post` (judging from the output of your first code snippet), then you should be able to use `find()` instead of `findAll()` :

```
for post in post_list:
    print post.find("span" , {"itemprop" : "name"}).text
```